# Set default encoding for Undertow embedded

Tags: java, undertow

I'm using Undertow for embedded HTTP server in my app. The default encoding is `ISO-8859-1` for URL encoding and query parameters. I want to use `UTF-8`. I did not find anything in documentation. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I setup `defaultEncoding` on [DeploynentInfo](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/api/DeploymentInfo.java#L313). It helped me.

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder =
    Servlets
        .deployment()
        .setClassLoader(Main.class.getClassLoader())
        .setDeploymentName("myapp").setContextPath("/myapp")
        .setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(9090, "localhost")
    .setHandler(manager.start())
    .build();

server.start();
```

For the current version of Undertow default encoding is UTF-8. Also for the non-deploy mode, you can use options to change the default encoding:

```
Undertow.builder()
       .setHandler(...)
       .setServerOption(UndertowOptions.URL_CHARSET, "UTF8")
       .addHttpListener(port, host)
       .build()
       .start();
```